# What am i doing wrong here? Golang

Tags: sockets, go

I have a problem when I try to connect to `php-fpm.service` on a Linux machine, the service listens on port `9000`, the service works perfectly and this is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    listener, err := net.Listen("unix", "127.0.0.1:9000")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Connection error: ", err)
    }

    for {
        fd, err := listener.Accept()

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("Accept error: ", err)
        }

        log.Print("a")
    }
}
```

The bad thing is that after this line of code: `fd, _ := listener.Accept()` nothing happens anymore, the code that follows is no longer executed, as you can see in the code above I have this line `log.Print("a")` but that text is never displayed on the console. What am I doing wrong? I hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: the docs show: 
function: Listen(network, address string) (Listener, error)
The **network** must be "tcp", "tcp4", "tcp6", "unix" or "unixpacket".

1. Could you show your error?

Comment: @Guolei with that code I don't get any error, just nothing happens, and when i use tcp i get this error: `Connection error: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:9000: bind: address already in use exit status 1`

Comment: address already in use exit status 1 -> you need change the address or just change the port. when you connected, this will wait for new message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is likely that you're creating a unix socket with the name "127.0.0.1:9000".  The address likely means you want either tcp or udp as the address type.

```
listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:9000")
```

With this change, I'm able to connect to the server and see your log message.

Comment: must be "tcp", "tcp4", "tcp6", "unix" or "unixpacket".

Comment: When i try it with your code i get this error: `2022/09/15 21:22:46 Connection error: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:9000: bind: address already in use
exit status 1` and there is nothing else occupying the port besides the service itself

Comment: Something is holding the port then.  Try a different one.

Comment: @StephenNewell i changed the port and i had the same result, and the same error. What can be the cause of that?

Comment: Check any firewall rules you have that would prevent port binding.  Try running the code in a different environment (e.g,, a VM or container).

Comment: @user1991 : I would say Stephen Newell spotted your issue (being: your initial code wasn't listening on the correct type of network). The fact that you need to look for an available tcp port on your host machine, and what services/firewalls are running on your machine, is beyond the scope of your original question. Would you agree to mark this answer as accepted ?

Comment: if you are running on a linux server, google for how to use `netstat`. `sudo netstat -ltp4` is a start, and should list all programs that currently listen on tcp with an IPv4 address on your machine. Do also check if you have a firewall installed.